# jquery function .prop() doesnot work properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, radiobuttonlist, prop

I am using jquery function .prop() to check a specific radio input from a group of radio input which is return by ajax.  it checked the desired input for a moment and then it again got unchecked. 
I created a button which when clicked call the function for ajax and the ajax return the radio input group list which is placed in the `<ul>` tag.
 
 The HTML code for `<ul>` tag.

```
<ul id= "list_option">
     // here ajax response will come
</ul>
```

code for button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary get_option" type="button" data-selected_option="2">click</button>
```

function called by button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.get_option', function(){

      var checked_answer_id = $(this).attr('data-selected_option');
      get_opt();
      $('#option_id_'+checked_answer_id).prop('checked',true);
   });
```

Note: I am using attr() function instead of data('selected_option') because attr was returning the value which for some reason data function is not. 
function for ajax:

```
function get_opt()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:{action:'get_option'},
            success:function(response)
            { $('#list_option').html(response);}
        })
    }
```

HTML code return from ajax_action.php page:

```
   $output=' 
     <li class="list-group-item border rounded border-success answer-item-list">
      <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input answer_option" type="radio" id="option_id_1" name="opt_grp" value="1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="option_id_1" > OPTION 1</label>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item border rounded border-success answer-item-list">
      <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input answer_option" type="radio" id="option_id_2" name="opt_grp" value="2">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="option_id_2"> OPTION 2</label>
      </div>
     </li>
    ';
  echo $output;
```

All the above code works fine except for the prop function which checked the desired radio input which is in this case is option 2 for a moment and then it gets unchecked. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/a09j67d2/. Are you sure that the HTML code returned from AJAX is parsed and inserted into the DOM, when the click event handler is fired?

Comment: Hey, remember, your get_opt() function triggers an *asynchronous* http-request. Your `jquery().prop()` gets called *before* this request has finished. You should put it into your succesd-function after your `.html()` call.

Comment: `$('#list_option').html(response);` so you're overwriting the `.prop("checked", true)` with the content from `ajax_action`.  Add a `console.log("1")` (2,3...) on each line so you can see the order they're executed.  Looks like you're expecting `$('#list_option').html(response);` to run before `.prop('checked',true);` when it won't.

Comment: thanks a lot cars10m and freedomn-m. its exactly as you said.I thought the statement will execute in sequence. so prop() statement will be executed when get_opt() will be finished. but now as you suggested i put the prop statement in the success function and its working fine. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the cool kids are doing it these days ;)

Use `async`/`await` for the function that calls `$.ajax`, awaiting the ajax call to complete, then returning the result to the calling function.

We use `.then()` so we don't have to also make out document ready anonymous function async and await `get_opt()`.   By using then, it will wait for get_opt to complete anyway.

You can then act on `result` inside of the `.then()` method as well as hopefull set the `prop` to checked on your radio button without it being overwritten later.

```
$(document).on('click', '.get_option', function(){

  var checked_answer_id = $(this).attr('data-selected_option');
  get_opt().then((result) => {
       $('#option_id_'+checked_answer_id).prop('checked',true); 
       $('#list_option').html(result);
  });
 });
```

---

```
async function get_opt() {

   let result;
   try {
      result = await $.ajax({
        url:"ajax_action.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{action:'get_option'},
      });
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. the problem was solved by placing prop() statement in the success call of ajax. I didn't try your method. but will try it later.

Comment: yeah, that works too.  i was just getting fancy with it.  :)